# Joomla Custom Module oop php isn't working

Tags: session, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to get session variables working with Joomla using their session code since php's sessions don't work. I am running into a problem trying to access session variables within the joomla custom code module editor though. When I try to access the session variable using the code:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', "../");
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$print $session->get('status');
```

I get nothing. If I take that same code and paste it into its own php file I can get the status variable fine. When I look at the plain text version of Joomla preview I see this:

```
get('status'); ?>
```

Doing some testing I think it's related to the '->' operand. Has anyone encountered this before and know how to fix it? I'm running Direct PHP and can print out strings and other variables inside of the module fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can't run PHP (or Javascript!) in Joomla articles without installing a plugin that supports it. I recommend using: http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla/DirectPHP-plugin.php
2. change `$print` to `print`

Try to comment out all the preceding lines and see if one of the "includes" is messing up the page:

```
/*define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', "../");
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );
*/
$session = JFactory::getSession();
print $session->get('status');
```

Comment: Yeah, I've got the plugin for it. The the javascript and php is running fine minus the one above problem. The $print was an oversight and upon fixing, still doesn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: @AustinMunro It can also be one of the included files. see updates in my answer.

Comment: It's not any of the includes or defines. Those are necessary for the joomla sessions to work and I have a separate php file on the server (not a custom joomla module) that utilizes those with no problem.

Comment: if what you see on screen is only the `get('status'); ?>` it means that  `print $session->get('status');` is not interpreted correctly. I would try remarking the code like in my example, and add `echo` before and after `getSession()` to see where is the source of the failure.

Comment: If you echo before the initialization of '$session = JFactory::getSession();' it breaks the page. If I echo after it still shows the 'get('status'); ?>' in the non source view of the wysiwyg editor.  


Something interesting to note is that if I set the session within the page itself and then echo it, it prints fine. If I then erase the setting, it still echoes, so it's definitely storing the session variable.  


The problem is that I need to set the session variable from a php file that is being used with an ajax call, and when that is set, the echo won't echo that session variable.

Comment: what did you `echo` that broke the page ? if you `echo "test\n";` it shouldn't brake anything. can you copy the code with the echo and the outputs to your question ? even add a print-screen of the article ?

Comment: I echoed '$session->get('status');'. I was under the impression that was what you were suggesting. If I echo a string before the code it echoes fine.

Comment: try changing it to: `$session =& JFactory::getSession();`

Comment: Same results as the ones before.

Comment: object(JSession)[11]
  protected '_state' => string 'active' (length=6)
  protected '_expire' => int 900
  protected '_store' => 
    object(JSessionStorageDatabase)[14]
      protected '_data' => null
      protected '_errors' => 
        array
          empty
  protected '_security' => 
    array
      0 => string 'fix_browser' (length=11)
  protected '_force_ssl' => boolean false
  protected '_errors' => 
    array
      empty

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13752/discussion-between-austin-munro-and-alfasin)

Comment: I've got go for an hour (might be able to chat later). but for now, I don't see the `status` property set. did you try to call `$session->('status','something');` somewhere in your code ?